# Allowing for Extensible App Architecture in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a VueJS app currently that will be open sourced. This app will have a similar internal version as well that includes some differences such as additional features / different auth mechanism etc. I want an architecture where the open source version of the app will be the source of truth. The internal version of the app will extend off the open source app and modify as needed. I am wondering how to achieve this with VueJS with as little code duplication as possible. Ideally, I want to be able to push changes to the open source repo and get updates to the internal version of the app as well.

Note: I have seen examples on the web of this sort of being done with Angular.
The app is split into modules and each module is shipped as an npm module. Then the internal version of the app downloads these modules as npm dependencies and then uses Angular's module system (NgModule) to do code extension.

Comment: Why wouldn't the same approach work with `Vue`?

Comment: It might work in Vue as well minus having the NgModule equivalent in Vue. I was just fishing for other ideas however that I have not seen.

Comment: I do this exact architecture with Vue(use lerna for packaging)

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example?